# Can we access AWS Glue Tables using jdbc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I need to access some tables which are there in AWS Glue which i am using as a metastore. I wanted to know if Glue provides any jdbc endpoint to connect to it just like HIVE does.
I understand that it is possible to read data into AWS glue from  other databases like MYSQL, Oracle etc using JDBC but my requirement is opposite and i have to read from AWS glue using JDBC. Please help if it is possible as I could not find a reference for this.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing the data from glue catalog, follow these steps:

1. Run the crawler and update the table in glue catalog.
2. To access these tables using JDBC or ODBC endpoint, you need athena.
3. Download the driver from this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html).
4. Read the docs for creating the url according to your region [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.9/docs/Simba+Athena+JDBC+Driver+Migration+Guide.pdf)

Also go through this [documentation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.9/docs/Simba+Athena+JDBC+Driver+Install+and+Configuration+Guide.pdf) for additional properties

Hope it helps